# How to use New-NetRoute without specifying the InterfaceIndex?

Tags: powershell

As you know, we can set up routing in Windows via

```
route add xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
```

and the OS decides which interface to use. Now, I want to do this in PowerShell with the command

```
New-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy" –InterfaceIndex w –NextHop zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
```

The problem here is that `InterfaceIndex` is mandatory here, but I want the OS to figure this out itself (as it does in the first command). How can I do this?

Comment: I would venture a guess this is where `Find-NetRoute` comes into play

Comment: Why don't you call `route` from Powershrell, then?

Comment: @Matt could you please elaborate? I'm not very good with PS

Comment: @Matt What's that? Is it from PS5?

Comment: @Vesper I need it to be powershell native command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never played with it myself but there is a cmdlet that does serve the purpose of what you are looking for. It is called [`Find-NetRoute`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372890(v=wps.630).aspx) and it finds the best local IP address and the best route to reach a remote address. That information is returned as a NetIPAddress object and NetRoute object. Both should contain the system chosen index. This is only supported on Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 currently.

A simple use would be to provide a remote address. The following code would return the `interfaceindex` into the variable `$bestIndex` which you could then use with `New-NetRoute`

```
$bestIndex = Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress "123.456.789.012" | select -first 1  -expandproperty interfaceindex

New-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/yy" –InterfaceIndex $bestIndex –NextHop zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
```

I encourage you to read more on the TechNet page I linked. I found it by reading up on how `New-NetRoute` worked.

Comment: "provide a remote address" wont the `zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz` address suffice?

Comment: @MarioStoilov Likely yes. I would experiment and see. Those values were copied from my testing.

Comment: @Matt So it's from 6.3 (Windows 8.1) only, I have here a 6.2 and no function. I'm about to write an equivalent.

Comment: I have v4 on 8.1 and the function is present. I just quoted the requirements from technet in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-NetIPAddress` to get your IP addresses along with the `InterfaceIndex` property that you can then pipe into `New-NetRoute`. You'll have to query if the (ip_address & subnet_mask) is equal to your (z.z.z.zz & subnet_mask). A sample function will look like this:

```
function Add-NetRouteByDestination {
    param ([String]$destinationPrefix,[System.Net.IPAddress][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $nextHop)
    $isipv6=$nextHop.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetworkV6" # thanks to type conversion
    if ($isipv6) {
        $af="IPv6"
    } else {
        $af="IPv4"
    } # address family filter
    # destination is expected to be "blabla/prefix", get prefix
    $ips=Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily $af
    $nhbytes=$nexthop.GetAddressBytes()
    $ifindex=0
    foreach ($ip in $ips) {
        $ipbytes=$ip.GetAddressBytes()
        $tmlen=$ip.prefixlength
        $matched=$true
        $index=0
        while ($tmlen -gt 0 -and $matched) {
            $b1=$ipbytes[$index]
            $b2=$nhbytes[$index]
            if ($tmlen -lt 8) {
                $bytemask=[byte](0,128,192,224,240,248,252,254)[$tmlen]
                $b1 = [byte]($b1 -band $bytemask)
                $b2 = [byte]($b2 -band $bytemask)
            }
            $matched=$b1 -eq $b2
            $index+=1
            $tmlen-=8
        } # a very stupid bitwise comparation
        if ($matched} { 
            $ifindex=$ip.interfaceindex 
            New-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix $destinationPrefix –InterfaceIndex $ifindex –NextHop $nextHop -ea stop
        } # this one matches gateway vs ip&mask, setting route
    }
}
```

Warning, the code is not tested and might contain typos. This code should work if there's no `Find-NetRoute` cmdlet available (Windows 8.0, Windows Server 2012).

Comment: The requirement for `Find-NetRoute` is Windows 8.1 not Windows 8.0 if that was your meaning.

Comment: @Matt I mean that if `Find-NetRoute` *is* available, better use that, if not, try using this code.

Comment: Also there's a possibility that I'm stupid, and no routing ever is required for IPv6 - if it's indeed so, only IPv4 addresses will be here, and part of the code is useless.